# Why I get retain circle in the second example?

Tags: swift, closures, retain-cycle

Why do we get strong reference circle in the second example, why we did not in the first example?

```
class Test1 {
    var name: String = "Ted"
    lazy var greeting  = { return "Hello \(self.name)" }()
    deinit{print("goodby1")} // No retain cycle here ..
}
var v1:Test1? = Test1()
v1?.greeting
v1 = nil //prints goodby1, dealocation done

class Test {
    var name: String = "Mery"
    lazy var greeting = {return "Hello \(self.name)"}
    deinit{print("goodby")} //retain cycle here 

}
var v: Test? = Test()
v!.greeting
v = nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the closure is executed one time, it returns a String, and that String is assigned `greeting`. There is no closure; nothing is captured. This is just an anonymous function. If you like, you can get rid of the `self.`, just like in a named function. The key point is that the type of `greeting` is `String`.

In the second example, `greeting` is a closure value, which captures `self`. Since `self` holds `greeting` and `greeting` holds `self`, there's a loop. The key point is that the type of `greeting` is `() -> String`. This is almost certainly a mistake, since this is not how `lazy` is intended to be used.

(`lazy` is a pretty weird feature in Swift, and was probably a bad idea to include in the langauge. I try to avoid it as much as possible. There are several subtle ways to use it incorrectly, so it's not surprising that it's bitten you.)

Comment: If I understand it right, if I use `[unowned self] in` and then use `self.name` in closure, then `self` should be deinitialized?

Comment: @RobertDresler That should be fine, since `unowned` does not hold a strong reference to its object.  Make sure only to use it when you know the variable captured (self, in this case) will never be nil when the closure gets called.  Otherwise, use `weak` and check if it has a value before using it.  Something like `guard let strongSelf = self else { /* bail */ }`.